# New dehumidifier making rhythmic pulsing noise. How to fix?

Tags: hvac, dehumidifier

I have a brand new dehumidifier that is making a rhythmic pulsing sound. I believe it is the compressor because it runs with just the fan for air testing and I do not hear it then. It becomes apparent within a few seconds after the compressor starts.

Here is a video of the sound: https://youtu.be/vmDZqBKPNWg

The unit is working in that it is removing water from the air but it has this annoying noise. Is this noise indicative of a defect or could the noise be fixable? I am wondering if possibly the noise is amplified by the room or the wooden platform that it sits on? It sits on a 32x32 wooden platform built from 2x4s with 1/2 inch plywood on top.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perform simple test.

Set it on solid ground. Noise still there ?

You build a boom box there that amplifies vibrations

Comment: Does it look like a boom box to you? This test isn’t so simple because I would have to cut out the pvc plumbing work that is connecting the condensate drain. That is a pain to reattach

Comment: @bradforj287 it is a resonance box. The vibrations have to go somewhere. You could build up cinder block platform. You could hold it with your hand and see is the sound diminishes.

Comment: The box is incredibly sturdy with the exception of the top which is only 1/2 inch plywood. When the unit is on the under side of the platform noticeably vibrates. What if I were to significantly increase the thickness of the top? Maybe use 3 or 4 sheets for 1.5-2 inches of thickness?

Comment: @bradforj287 have you ever felt a stereo speaker? It's quite solid and incredibly sturdy, yet it works _incredibly_ well as a resonance chamber for producing music. As a matter of fact, it's _precisely_ this sturdiness that is amplifying the resonance. Find some foam from a recent purchase (just about any sort of shipping foam) and replace the wooden blocks that the feet sit on with this foam and see how much quieter it is.

Comment: Heck, if all you have available right now are a couple of the "air pockets" that they put in boxes to "pack" things (looking at you, Amazon), balancing it on those will isolate the vibrations of the dehumidifier from the box and significantly reduce the sound. They won't last long, but they'll prove to you that this is the fix, and should last long enough for you to find something else as a permanent fix.

Comment: @FreeMan but a speaker has one part of it (the paper cone) that vibrates in order to produce the music. In my case the top plywood panel is vibrating which presumably is enhancing the noise. If I thicken the plywood top the vibrations would reduce. No?

Comment: You will want to soften it, not thicken it.  I would get a couple of old towels and put those under.  Plus that is cheaper than buying thick wood.  I have a lot of old towels.